# Initializing hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I frequently write something like this:

```
a_hash['x'] ? a_hash['x'] += ' some more text' : a_hash['x'] = 'first text'
```

There ought to be a better way to do this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two ways to create initial values with for a `Hash`.

One is to pass a single object in to `Hash.new`.  This works well in many situations, especially if the object is a frozen value, but if the object has internal state, this may have unexpected side-effects.  Since the same object is shared between *all* keys without an assigned value, modifying the internal state for one will show up in all.

```
a_hash = Hash.new "initial value"
a_hash['a'] #=> "initial value"
# op= methods don't modify internal state (usually), since they assign a new
# value for the key.
a_hash['b'] += ' owned by b' #=> "initial value owned by b"
# other methods, like #<< and #gsub modify the state of the string
a_hash['c'].gsub!(/initial/, "c's")
a_hash['d'] << " modified by d"
a_hash['e'] #=> "c's value modified by d"
```

Another initialization method is to pass `Hash.new` a block, which is invoked each time a value is requested for a key that has no value.  This allows you to use a distinct value for each key.

```
another_hash = Hash.new { "new initial value" }
another_hash['a'] #=> "new initial value" 
# op= methods still work as expected
another_hash['b'] += ' owned by b'
# however, if you don't assign the modified value, it's lost,
# since the hash rechecks the block every time an unassigned key's value is asked for
another_hash['c'] << " owned by c" #=> "new initial value owned by c"
another_hash['c'] #=> "new initial value"
```

The block is passed two arguments: the hash being asked for a value, and the key used.  This gives you the option of assigning a value for that key, so that the same object will be presented each time a particular key is given.

```
yet_another_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "#{key}'s initial value" }
yet_another_hash['a'] #=> "a's initial value"
yet_another_hash['b'] #=> "b's initial value"
yet_another_hash['c'].gsub!('initial', 'awesome')
yet_another_hash['c'] #=> "c's awesome value"
yet_another_hash #=> { "a" => "a's initial value", "b" => "b's initial value", "c" => "c's awesome value" }
```

This last method is the one I most often use.  It's also useful for caching the result of an expensive calculation.

Comment: initialize with a block is one I will start using. Good one!

Comment: it would be nice mentioning that the later case using a block, can also be used to set a default value when retrieving a value with the Hash#fetch method, since many times you might receive a Hash that was created somewhere else.

Comment: Didn't know about [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), thanks!  Worth noting that the block passed to `#fetch` is a bit different, it doesn't get the hash table as a parameter during a miss.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify the initial value when you create your hash:

```
a_hash = { 'x' => 'first text' }
// ...
a_hash['x'] << ' some more text'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the hash to collect strings, I assume you simply want to make sure that you don't get an error when appending. Therefore, I'd make the hash default the empty string. Then you can append without error, no matter the hash key.

```
a_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=""}

texts = ['first text', ' some more text']

texts.each do |text|
  a_hash['x'] << text
end

puts a_hash['x'] #=> 'first text some more text'
```

Comment: @rampion, you are correct. The block form to Hash.new slipped my mind. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Hash, in its first argument, have a default value for  the keys. This way

```
>> a_hash = Hash.new "first text"
=> {}
>> a_hash['a']
=> "first text"
>> a_hash['b'] += ", edit"
=> "first text, edit"
```

Comment: The danger of this is that the *same* string object is used for all keys.  So modicications to that string will be seen across all of them.  That is if we use `<<` : `a_hash['c'] << " by c" #=> "first text by c"`, then `a_hash['d'] #=> "first text by c"`

Comment: This gets at what I want to do if I initialize a_hash w/ an empty string: a_hash = Hash.new "", then I can add arbitrary text to arbitrary keys using +=

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to mess with the `default=` value (existing hash), you can shorten your code by using `fetch(key [, default])` as a look-up with a default value:

```
a_hash['x'] = a_hash.fetch('x', 'first_text') + ' some more text'
```