# How to return a string when there is an non-existent element in a hash using an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have this hash and this array, and execute the following command...

```
hash={"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4,"e"=>5,"f"=>6}
array=["b","a","c","f","z","q"]
print hash.values_at(*array).compact
```

So I want it to return something like:

```
#=> [2,1,3,6,"invalid","invalid"]
```

Is there a way to declare all other elements non-existent in the hash as "invalid", without declaring one by one (e.g. "g"=>"invalid", "h"=>"invalid"...)?

Comment: yeah, just set `hash.default = "invalid"`. From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990812/initializing-hashes)

Answer (score 3):

If a hash has to respond with a default value for a nonexistent key, then this value has to be set. Usually it is set on the initialization of the hash:

```
hash = Hash.new("invalid")
```

but it can be done anytime

```
hash={"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4,"e"=>5,"f"=>6}
array=["b","a","c","f","z","q"]

hash.default = "invalid"
p hash.values_at(*array)  #compact is superfluous

# => [2, 1, 3, 6, "invalid", "invalid"]
```

Comment: Note that this mutates `hash`.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.map do |key|
  hash.fetch key, 'invalid'
end
```

if fetch is called with one argument, then if the key doesn't exist it will raise an error. However an optional second argument can set a custom return value for nonexistent keys.

The benefit of this over `hash.default=` or passing the default in the Hash constructor is that the hash itself is not changed, so if you lookup a nonexistent key in the future it will return nil as expected instead of 'invalid'.

Comment: Good explanation. Consider providing a link to the doc [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
array.map { |key|
    hash.has_key?(key) ? hash[key] : 'invalid'
}
```